# React.js detect outdated browser and stop render

Tags: reactjs

I know that the support of Internet Explorer 8 has been discontinued.
My app breaks in IE8 throwing a lot of errors in console and showing the blank screen. There is now any reason to support an outdated browsers but the errors in console and blank screen makes big sense.
    So I wonder is there an special plug-in which could detect a browser's version before the render process and in case if it detects an outdated version - stop render(bootstrap of whole app) and display custom message? Does somebody done something similar?

Comment: Perhaps you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-browser-detection to bootstrap within React and either render a very simple message, or proceed with the entire app, but obviously this still means running React regardless, which might not solve your problem if it's the React core that causes the issues.

Comment: Yes, I saw this plug-in, but as app crashes in IE8 it won't solve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

There is no plugin as of now which can detect outdated version and rendering is based on react lifecycle by checking Vdom